# Asp.net core EF6 Oracle database with IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Tags: asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

Searched a lot about how to solve this, but couldn't find solution

I have application on MVC core with oracle database.
I just want to add functionality for user can sign in  into the system.

I was Using ApplicationDbcontext like this :

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(OracleConf))]
    public class ApplicationDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
```

And OracleConf class:

```
namespace Data
{
    public class OracleConf
      : DbConfiguration
    {
        public OracleConf()
        {
            SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);
            SetProviderFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", OracleClientFactory.Instance);
        }
    }
}
```

Now i want implement IdentityDbContext but it doesn't make any result.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Need a lot more info. You added Identity Nuget packages? Setup a context (or change you context to inherit IndentityDbContext)? Code first or Model First?

Comment: Yes i have added Identyti packages, Model First. And also i have inherited context from IndentityDbContext. But i don't know how to send connectionString in DbContextOptions on creation of Context